Determining which KML to use when there are multiple root KMLs in a KMZ
We are looking to read simple KMZs and convert them to GeoJSON.
With this, we want to handle the case where the user has supplied a KMZ that has multiple root KMLs. This isn't a proper way to package a KMZ, but it's not considered to be outright invalid by Google Earth (whose behavior we would like to match).
The Google Earth "Spec" for KMZs says:

When Google Earth opens a KMZ file, it scans the file, looking for the first .kml file in this list. It ignores all subsequent .kml files, if any, in the archive. If the archive contains multiple .kml files, you cannot be sure which one will be found first, so you need to include only one.

What does first mean in this context? Is this simply the first file as defined by the original zip order? Is there anything authoritative on the subject?
I thought I found the code responsible, but the behavior it describes appears to contradict both the first "Spec" that I linked to, as well as behavior I've seen. The code suggests that it looks for a file called "doc.kml", but I've confirmed in at least the browser version of Earth that the root KML doesn't need to be called "doc". The "Spec" also says that the name "doc" is largely a convention.
Any insight here?

From some experimentation with the Browser version of Google Earth, it appears to use the first KML file when sorted alphabetically by file name (case insensitive). It also appears to not prefer files called "doc.kml".
This could be behavior defined by Google Earth, or it could be the fact that the Ubuntu's Archive Manager re-orders the files within the archive based on file name.

According to the documentation you quoted, it really doesn't matter.  It explicitly says that any one of them could be found "first".  The fact that it says that you should include only one, and that if you include more any of them can be considered "first" (ie, the one to use), means that you can use any one of them.  That being said, you should aim to be consistent, at least internally, and also with Google Earth.  Therefore "first" alphabetically sounds like the way to go.
